# Number Guessing Game: difficulty setting

Tags: c#, if-statement

This is how I am generating my random number, but I would like to be able to have the user select the difficulty: easy = 1-10, intermediate = 1-50, hard = 1-100. I was wondering how this could be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
    class HiLow
    {
        private int number;

        public int Number
        {
            get
            {
                return number;
            }
        }

        public HiLow(int taker)
        {
            number = new Random().Next(taker);
        }
    }
}

{
    class HiLowUI
    {
        public void Welcome()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to the HighLow Game!" +
                "\n\nInstructions: \nTry to guess the number between the selected difficulty range." + 
                "\nIf you guess the right number you win!");

            Console.WriteLine("\nDifficulty: \n[1] (1-10) Easy \n[2] (1-50) Intermediate \n[3] (1-100) Hard");

        }
        public void Play()
        {
            Welcome();

            while (true)
            {
                HiLow hi = null;
                int number = hi.Number;
                int guess;
                int attempts = 0;

                int difficulty = PromptForInt("Select difficulty");
                if (difficulty == 1)
                {
                   hi = new HiLow(10);
                }
                else if (difficulty == 2)
                {
                    hi = new HiLow(50);
                }
                else if (difficulty == 3)
                {
                    hi = new HiLow(100);
                }

                for (guess = PromptForInt("\nEnter your guess! "); guess != number; guess = PromptForInt("\nEnter your guess! "))
                {
                    if (guess < number)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Higher");
                        attempts++;
                    }
                    else if (guess > number)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Lower");
                        attempts++;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nIt took you {0} attempts, but you've won!\n{1} was the correct number!\n", attempts, number);
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (y/n)");

                if (Console.ReadLine() != "y") break;
            }
        }
        private int PromptForInt(string prompt)
        {
            int value;
            Console.Write(prompt);
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value);
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have the user's setting, add an option to the constructor of HiLow for the maximum number.  Use that number for generating the random number.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor:

```
public HiLow(int upperLimit)
{
    number = new Random().Next(upperLimit);
}
```

Within your `Play()` method, you would instantiate the `HiLow` class as one of:

```
HiLow hi = new HiLow(10);  // easy
HiLow hi = new HiLow(50);  // medium
HiLow hi = new HiLow(100); // hard
```

Then simply prompt the user for their desired level of difficulty before you enter the `Play()` method, and pass in whatever value they chose to the `HiLow()` constructor.

Personally, I would pass in the difficulty to the `Play()` method, and use a `switch()` or `if()` statement to determine which one to call:

```
public void Play(int difficulty)
{
    while (true)
    {
        HiLow hi = null;
        if (difficulty == 0)      // Easy
        {
            hi = new HiLow(10);
        }
        else if (difficulty == 1) // Medium
        {
            hi = new HiLow(50);
        }
        else if (difficulty == 2) // Hard
        {
            hi = new HiLow(100);
        }
        else if (difficulty == 3) // Much harder
        {
            hi = new HiLow(5000);
        }
        else if (difficulty == 4) // Mwa-ha-ha
        {
            hi = new HiLow(99999999);
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: so all of the HiLow hi = new HiLow (10) etc should be added to Play() or just one?

Comment: You would wrap them in an `if()` statement: `if (difficulty == 0) { hi = new HiLow(10); } else if (difficulty == 1) { hi = new HiLow(50; } ...` and so on.

Comment: public HiLow(setting)
    {
        number = new Random().Next(setting);
    }
so this is what I've got now and it says that I have invalid arguments. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Where did you define 'setting'? It needs to be `public HiLow(int setting)`, not just `...(setting)`.

Comment: Ahh fixed that but when I run it I get an error that says 'System.NullReferenceException' it happens at the part 

**HiLow hi = null;**

Comment: Edit your original post, and append (don't remove the old stuff) what you have now. It's easier to see where an error is when we've got code to work with.

Comment: I'd actually think it's the `int number = hi.Number` line below that one, since it's trying to dereference `hi` (which is null).